# Can't shutdown the laptop with dual boot Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, shutdown, thinkpad

On a three day old [Ideapad 330-15lch](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Lenovo%20Laptops/ideapad%20330%20(15_)%20Intel/ideapad_330_15Intel_Platform_Specifications.pdf) with Ubuntu 18.04 in a dual boot (vs Windows 10), when clicking on power off or restart, the Lenovo laptop freezes. Keyboard and mouse do not react, it does not shutdown, and I have to force shutdown the laptop.  The same occurs when I do

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: _Mohamed Eid Khedr_, thank you! I did not mention it's better to delete the Comment above, and when replying to a suggestion, instead click {edit] and add to your Question instead. Comments can pile up and get hidden, whereas everyone can always see all of the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you check for the existence of snap services with

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep snap
```

Stop each of the services (except for `snapd.socket`) not used, then try shutdown again.